# iOS8 incorrrect value of UIView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize with Size Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

I've faced strange issue with method `UIView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` when `Size Classes` are being on on iOS 8.
As example I'm usign Paul's tutorial project for auto height cell. Also project with mine modifications for demonstrate purpose, can be found [here](https://github.com/Dudi00/AutoLayoutForUITableViewCell)

So on iOS 7 it looks like nice.

[image][image]

---

But on iOS 8 method return much more lesser value and then cells are starting to breaking apart.

[image][image]

---

This issue is gone when `Size Classes` is being off. I don't know how to aproach this and at this point only solution I know is turn of `Size Classes`.

### Code

**ViewController.m** (108 lines)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    
    NSMutableArray *_fontArray;
    NSMutableArray *_quoteArray;
    
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomTableViewCell *customCell;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    
//    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    
    _fontArray = [[UIFont familyNames] mutableCopy];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        [_fontArray addObjectsFromArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Size: %d", [_fontArray count]);
    
    _quoteArray = [@[@"For the past 33 years, I have looked in the mirror every morning and asked myself: 'If today were the last day of my life, would I want to do what I am about to do today?' And whenever the answer has been 'No' for too many days in a row, I know I need to change something. -Steve Jobs",
                     @"Be a yardstick of quality. Some people aren't used to an environment where excellence is expected. - Steve Jobs",
                     @"Innovation distinguishes between a leader and a follower. -Steve Jobs"] mutableCopy];
    
 
    // Use iOS 8 new auto sizing feature for heights (don't need to calculate yourself)
//    _tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    return [_fontArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    
    cell.fontNameLabel.text = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    
    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [_quoteArray count];
    cell.quoteLabel.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    cell.quoteLabel2.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    NSString *fontName = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];
    cell.quoteLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];
    return cell;
    
}

// NOTE: in iOS 8 you can use the automatic height calculations from AutoLayout,
//  and you can avoid writing this height method. Just comment it out, and uncomment
//  the line in viewDidLoad for
//  _tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    // Calculate a height based on a cell
    if(!self.customCell) {
        self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }
    
    // Configure the cell
    self.customCell.fontNameLabel.text = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    
    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [_quoteArray count];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel2.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    NSString *fontName = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];

    
    // Layout the cell
    
    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];
    
    // Get the height for the cell

    CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    
    // Padding of 1 point (cell separator)
    CGFloat separatorHeight = 1;
    NSLog(@"%f",height);
    
    return height + separatorHeight;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    return 140;
    
}

@end
```

**CustomTableViewCell.h** (10 lines)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *quoteLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fontNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *quoteLabel2;

@end
```

**CustomTableViewCell.m** (39 lines)

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

// CODE FIX layouts by setting the maxPreferredWidth on any UILabel that can be
//  multiline – you may have to do similar settings to other UI elements
//  This logic fixes the layout for any UILabels that don't go up to the margins, they
//  might be offset by a constraint that isn't the standard.

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.fontNameLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.fontNameLabel.frame.size.width;
    self.quoteLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.quoteLabel.frame.size.width;
    self.quoteLabel2.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.quoteLabel2.frame.size.width;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely because when you use a prototype cell created with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, the cell returned has no size class because it is not part of a view hierarchy and thus does not have a `traitCollection` associated with it.

I worked around this by temporarily adding the cell to the table view, doing the sizing and then removing it. While added, the customCell acquires the size class of the controller and layout then uses any size class related fonts, constraints etc... The real cells do not have the same issue as they have a size class by being part of the UITableView.

So try changing your height calculation as follows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Calculate a height based on a cell
    if(!self.customCell) {
        self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }

    // ***
    // *** Add custom cell to the table view so it obtains a size class
    // *** for layout. Also mark it as needing layout.
    // ***
    [self.tableView addSubview:customCell];
    [customCell setNeedsLayout];

    // Configure the cell
    self.customCell.fontNameLabel.text = _fontArray[indexPath.row];

    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [_quoteArray count];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel2.text = _quoteArray[quoteIndex];
    NSString *fontName = _fontArray[indexPath.row];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:17];


    // Layout the cell

    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];

    // Get the height for the cell

    CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    // Padding of 1 point (cell separator)
    CGFloat separatorHeight = 1;
    NSLog(@"%f",height);

    // ***
    // *** Remove cell from the table view
    // ***
    [customCell removeFromSuperview];

    return height + separatorHeight;
}
```

Comment: @Dudi Pretty sure the main performance hit is the actual size calculation. Adding/removing a view should be relatively cheap. The `traitCollection` is a read only property of the UITraitEnvironment interface. The other option would be to override the traitCollection property getter and provide a default when the real one is nil somehow. The posted method also deals with popovers etc which have different size classes from the code which presents them (e.g iPad).  Overriding approach would require you to work out the right size class somehow.